# php foreach separate multiple data in table column

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I want to do is separate data in 2 or 3 table column

**here is my code, but my code now is only display in one column**

```
<?php if(isset($queue_record)) : foreach($queue_record as $row) : ?>

<tr>
<td>
<label class="checkbox ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_queue[]" id="inlineCheckbox1"
          class="inlineCheckbox1" value="<?php echo $row->tenantqueueid; ?>">
          <?php echo $row->queuename; ?>
</label>
</td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**What I actually want to display, but the screenshot data just a sample, actually the 2 column data are different**

[image]

Comment: So you want to do 1 MySQL query that will return 3 columns and you would like to make 3 checkbox columns out of that ? can you elaborate more on your problem ? to me it seems a simple html issue as you are currently asking. Or you want to split your current long results into several columns

Comment: Hi Prix, what I want to do is with 1 MYSQL query split long result into several columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to to do something like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($queue_record)){
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Column 1 Header</th>";
    echo "<th>Column 2 Header</th>";
    echo "<th>Column 3 Header</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $num_cols = 3; //We set the number of columns
    $current_col = 0;
foreach($queue_record as $row):
if($current_col == "0")echo "<tr>"; //Creates a new row if $curent_col equals to 0
?>
<td>
<label class="checkbox ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_queue[]" id="inlineCheckbox1"
          class="inlineCheckbox1" value="<?php echo $row->tenantqueueid; ?>">
          <?php echo $row->queuename; ?>
</label>
</td>
<?php 
   if($current_col == $num_cols-1){ // Close the row if $current_col equals to 2 in the example ($num_cols -1)
       echo "</tr>";
       $current_col = 0;
   }else{
       $current_col++;
   }
endforeach;
echo "</table>";

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You are save my life as well :) haha
Thanks for this code!